# vertexShader in a 2D game?

Tags: c#, xna, directx, 2d, hlsl

I searched some tutorials to learn HLSL and every tutorials I found talked about VertexShader and PixelShader. (the tutorials used a 3D game as example).

So I don't know if vertexShader is usefull for 2D games.
As I know, a 2D game doesn't have any vertex right ?

I have to use shader as post-processing.
My question is : `Could you tell me if I have to learn VertexShader for my 2D game ?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2D graphics in XNA (and Direct3D, OpenGL, etc) are achieved by rendering what is essentially a 3D scene with an **orthographic** projection that basically disregards the depth of the vertices that it projects (things don't get smaller as they get further away). You could create your own orthographic projection matrix with `Matrix.CreateOrthographic`.

While you could render arbitrary 3D geometry this way, sprite rendering - like `SpriteBatch` - simply draws camera-facing "quads" (a square or rectangle made up of 2 triangles formed by 4 vertices). These quads have 3D coordinates - the orthographic projection simply ignores the Z axis.

A **vertex shader** basically runs on the GPU and manipulates the vertices you pass in, before the triangles that they form are rasterised. You certainly **can** use a vertex shader on these vertices that are used for 2D rendering.

For all modern hardware, vertex transformations - including the above-mentioned orthographic projection transformation - are usually done in the vertex shader. This is basically boilerplate, and it's unusual to use complicated vertex shaders in a 2D game. But it's not unheard of - for example my own game [Dark](http://andrewrussell.net/dark/) uses a vertex shader to do 2D shadow projection.

But, if you are using `SpriteBatch`, and all you want is a **pixel shader**, then you can just omit the `VertexShader` from your `.fx` file - your pixel shader will still work. (To use it, load it as an `Effect` and pass it to [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433700.aspx) of `SpriteBatch.Begin`).

If you don't replace it, `SpriteBatch` will use its default vertex shader. You can view the source for it [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/stock_effects). It does a single matrix transformation (the passed matrix being an orthographic projection matrix, multiplied by an optional matrix passed to `Begin`).

Comment: Thx a lot andrew, as usual. For a ripple (or shockwave effect) for example, can I create these effects without vertexShader ?

Comment: If you use `SpriteBatch`, yes. If you draw the quad yourself you will need to provide (a simple) one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. If you're focusing your attention on `2D` game, you may avoid learging *Shaders* in order to complete your projects.

Another option *may be*, rendering in `2D` the scene that is actually generated in `3D`, so in other words, you render a *projection* of your `3D` scene to some surface. In this case, you may come to need to use them, especially if you would like to do some cool transformations, without CPU (also often it's an only option).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited my post for more visibility. Actually, I WANT to use shader and my game is in **2D**. The right question is "Are there Vertex in 2D games ?" and "is VertexShader is usefull for 2D games" ? ^^

Comment: @Sharpnel: as I said if what you render is a *projection* to (say) XY plane, you definitely can use them, so can apply complicated transformations to your 3D model, that after projected to 2D surface and rendered on the screen.

Comment: For you, what is a 3D model in a 2D game ?

Comment: Vertex shader is a program that manipulates vertex (its different ptoperties) along the rendering/transformation pipeline. So basaically you can generate a mesh model, but render it on 2D surface. You actually loos on cool (perspective) meaning of 3D world, but it's something that you *can* do. I never did it, cause if you want to learn shaders, write complete 3D program.